# Java strsubstitutor with double $$ varaible

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang

I have a question about the strsubstitutor with double $$ varible, I have the following code:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("hello", "hello");
String templateString = "The ${hello} $${test}.";
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(params);
String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
System.out.println(resolvedString);
```

The output is `hello ${test}`

If the `test` variable is with double `$`, and it can not be replaced, why the output is `${test}`? Should not be still `$${test}`?

Comment: `$$` is an escaped `$`, so it substitutes that first then is it left with `{test}`.

Comment: sorry, can you explain it a bit more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `$${test}` becomes `${test}` is that `${...}` is a reserved keyword for `StrSubstitutor` and adding an extra `$` in front of it is used to escape it (i.e. if you want to get a literal `${...}` in output).

Given that, [the documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html#setPreserveEscapes-boolean-) says that by default `setPreserveEscapes` is set to `false` and this means that:

> If set to **true**, the escape character is retained during substitution (e.g. $${this-is-escaped} remains $${this-is-escaped}). If set to **false**, the escape character is removed during substitution (e.g. $${this-is-escaped} becomes ${this-is-escaped}). The default value is **false**

So if you want `$${test}` in output you should set `setPreserveEscapes(true)` before replacing the variables.

Comment: looks like this setPreserveEscapes is deprecated, is there any new function for that to use?

Comment: @ratzip actually the entire class is deprecated in favour of [`StringSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html)